# How to convert a date column of a R dataframe to a certain string format

Tags: r

I want to convert a column of a dataframe in R into a new column with a string format and extract for example only the **day** or the **month**. The format of the dataframe could look like this, where the date has already the type Date:

```
Name,Date,Salary
Bob,12/31/18,1000
Alice,10/28/18,100
John,05/06/17,200
```

So the target df should look like this:

```
Name,Date,Day,Month,Salary
Bob,12/31/18,31,12,1000
Alice,10/28/18,28,10,100
John,05/06/17,06,05,200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format`.  The `[...]` part at the end can be omitted if the order of columns is not important.

```
transform(DF, Day = format(Date, "%d"), Month = format(Date, "%m"))[
  c("Name", "Date", "Day", "Month", "Salary")]
```

giving:

```
   Name       Date Day Month Salary
1   Bob 2018-12-31  31    12   1000
2 Alice 2018-10-28  28    10    100
3  John 2017-05-06  06    05    200
```

There is also some question of whether you really need to add Day and Month columns in the first place given that the Date is already a column.  It might be more convenient to extract it on the fly when you need it depending on what you are doing with it.

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "Name,Date,Salary
Bob,12/31/18,1000
Alice,10/28/18,100
John,05/06/17,200"

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

Comment: Just found out that Test$Day <-format(Test$Date, "%d") 
Test$Month <-format(Test$Date, "%m") also leads to the same solution

Comment: It's similar but not exactly the same because it modifies `test` whereas `transform` preserves it outputting the result.  You can write `test <- transform(...)` if you want to overwrite the input or you can write `test2 <- transform(...)` if you want to preserve the input so you can recreate it from scratch, say.

Answer (score 2):

For a base R solution, we can try using first `as.Date` to convert your string dates to bona fide R dates.  Then, we can convert those dates to POSIXlt objects, in order to extract the day and month components.

```
x <- "12/31/18"
date <- as.Date(x, "%m/%d/%y")
day <- as.POSIXlt(date)$yday + 1
month <- as.POSIXlt(date)$mon + 1

day
month

[1] 365
[1] 12
```

### Demo